# Get Weekday from Date - Swift 3

Tags: xcode, date, swift3

I have looked around a bit, but didnt find a quick answer for this in swift 3. I get todays weekday like this:

```
let weekday = Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: Date())
```

But instead, i would like to get the weekday of a given date.
How is this done?
Thanx

Comment: The same way. What's the problem? Just use "the given date" instead of `Date()`.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Presumably you have a `Date` already?

```
let weekday = Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: myDate)
```

Maybe you want the name of the weekday?

```
let f = DateFormatter()

f.weekdaySymbols[Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: Date()) - 1]
```

The `-1` is added at the end because Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: Date()) returns values from 1-7 but weekdaySymbols expects array indices.

Investigate the `NSCalendar`/`DateComponents` api or edit your question to be more specific if you need help with the DateComponents api.

Comment: Using `Calendar` as `.iso8601` and an UTC Date the index which I got from my Calendar needs to be subtracted by 1. When the Date was Sunday I got an Index out of range at `f.shortWeekdaySymbols[dayIndex]` because my Day Index was `7`

Comment: Right, -1 to be within array bounds.

Comment: i think there is something wrong here, i think weekdays always start with Monday in `weekdaySymbols`, because in Sunday i have weekday component (int) = 1, receiving Monday as a result. Calendar.current is gregorian London Time

Answer (score 62):

```
let date = Date()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy" // OR "dd-MM-yyyy"

let currentDateString: String = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
print("Current date is \(currentDateString)")
```

**Current date is Monday, June 29, 2017**

Comment: dateFormat is set twice here. What about other languages? How would you handle the different date formats displayed in different languages e.g. 01/25/2018 vs. 25.01.2018?

Comment: Upvote this answer because i found't searching for a dateFormat for weekday.

But the @joedaniels it's the correct answer for the question

Answer (score 27):

Swift5 get week day from DateFormatter

```
 func getTodayWeekDay()-> String{
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
        let weekDay = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
        return weekDay
  }

 //eg: // "EEEE" --> "Friday" 
       // "EEE"  --> "Fri"
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer. as the result of this is "Friday", how to shorten it to "Fri"?

Comment: Hi @ThaoTran use "EEE" for Fri , Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Weekday by default consider first weekday as Sunday, if you wanna support generic context use this extension.

```
extension Date {

    var calendar: Calendar { Calendar.current }

    var weekday: Int {
        (calendar.component(.weekday, from: self) - calendar.firstWeekday + 7) % 7 + 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To get local format you can use:

```
extension Date{

func stringValueFullWithTime()-> String?{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .full
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = . short
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
    return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
}
```

This will print as german local: 
**Sonntag, 11. November 2018 um 11:17**

Comment: `dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current` did not work for me. I had to specify the correct local using `Locale(identifier: "de_DE")`.

Answer (score 2):

> If you want dayNumber component in TimeZone

```
func dayNumberOfWeek() -> Int? {
    let timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "EDT")
    let component =  Calendar.current.dateComponents(in: timeZone!, from: self)
    return  component.day
}
```

Comment: returns the day number, not thee weekday