# Weekday component issue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to use weekday from calendar. I should receive Monday but somehow I'm receiving Tuesday. Any ideas why?

```
let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1519654139)
var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 3600)!

let weekDayComponent = calendar.component(Calendar.Component.weekday, from: date)
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE EEEE"
print("Date formatter says it's " + dateFormatter.string(from: date))
print("Weekday component is \(weekDayComponent)")
```

Console output:

> Date formatter says it's Mon Monday
>   Weekday component is 2

[EDIT]: Why I'm receiving 2, not 1? yes, value of `calendar.firstWeekday` is 1.

Comment: Did you search on SOF ? Follow this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41068860/get-weekday-from-date-swift-3

Comment: @Szu 1 is Sunday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Week in gregorian calendar starts with Sunday, therefore it is a correct behavior, 2 is Monday. [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdatecomponents/1410442-weekday) clearly states that:

> Weekday units are the numbers 1 through n, where n is the number of days in the week. For example, in the Gregorian calendar, n is 7 and Sunday is represented by 1.