# How to get the day of the week from a date in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I can print the date in this format: Mon, Mar 19, 2018, but I am not sure how to get the Day of the week in this format.

Please help

Comment: What does *Day of the week* mean?

Comment: like "Tuesday".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
// uncomment to enforce the US locale
// dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en-US") 
dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("EEE MMM d yyyy")
print(dateFormatter.string(from: Date())) // "Tue, Mar 20, 2018" for en-US locale
```

Note that I am using a template to provide the exact format, therefore the format will be properly localized in every language.

Comment: @Sh_Khan Exactly what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 12):

To get the day for a particular date:

```
let customDateFormatter = DateFormatter()

print(customDateFormatter.weekdaySymbols[Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: Date())])
```

// "Wednesday"

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41068860/get-weekday-from-date-swift-3)

Answer (score 3):

Rather than needing to spell out a date format. I would simplify it further to:

```
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .full
```

Or if you just want the day:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
```

Answer (score 2):

With swift 4

```
 func timeStamp()->String {

      let dateFormater = DateFormatter()
      dateFormater.locale = Locale(identifier: "en-US") 
      dateFormater.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("EEE MMM d yyyy")

      return dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
    }
```

Use it.

```
let getTimeStamp = timeStamp()
   print(getTimeStamp)
```

Comment: Where is `Mon` as op expected??

Comment: Don't use `NSDateFormatter` in Swift 3+ and please don't improve your answer by *pirating* others. 

Comment: This is exactly the same as my answer

Comment: Yes we did on same time so i can't delete my answer. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, MMM dd, yyyy"

For dat of week in alphabets, you use EEEE or EEE similar to MMM & yyyy for month year.

Comment: what about `get the Day of the week in this format`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724180/converting-a-date-format-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

The best way to change your date is follow this method.

```
func ChangeDateFormat(date:String,FromFormat: String, ToFormat: String) -> String {
    let dateFormatter1 = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter1.dateFormat = FromFormat
    let myDate = dateFormatter1.date(from: date)
    dateFormatter1.dateFormat = ToFormat
    if(myDate != nil){
        let Date = dateFormatter1.string(from: myDate!)
        return Date
    }
    else{
        return ""
    }
}
```

and then you can use this method like

```
String(ChangeDateFormat(date: StartDate, FromFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a", ToFormat: "MMM d, yyyy"))
```

You can pass your date format in which format do you want in your case it should be

```
  String(ChangeDateFormat(date: StartDate, FromFormat: "Pass your date format", ToFormat: "EEE MMM d, yyyy"))
```

Comment: please, learn to use `if let` or `guard let`. Also please use swift naming conventions, not conventions from other languages.